# How do I use the darker() method?

Tags: java

I can't find out how to make a color darker with the darker() method. Every time I run this method, the output is the same for both print lines.

```
public void makeDarker() {
    
    System.out.println(getColor());
    
    getColor().darker();
    
    System.out.println(getColor());
}
```

Output:

java.awt.Color[r=200,g=200,b=200]

java.awt.Color[r=200,g=200,b=200]

Answer (score 3):

The `darker()` method returns a new instance of the Color object so you need to assign it to a variable:

```
Color darkerColor = getColor().darker();
System.out.println( darkerColor );
```

You need to read the API when using a new method to see if it has parameters or if it return a value.

Answer (score 1):

`getColor()` will keep returning the same value, and calling `.darker()` on the Color object won't magically change the object returned by the `getColor()` method. Instead perhaps what you want to do is set the Color property using the new value:

```
setColor(getColor().darker());
```